# Need to add request headers to every request in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, requestheader

I'm trying to add a header value to every request via Apache (ver 2.2). 
I've edited my VirtualHost to include the following vaiations:
(I've tried both RequestHeader and Header, add and set in all of these cases)

```
RequestHeader set X-test_url "Test"
```

or

```
<Directory />
  RequestHeader set X-test_url "Test"
</Directory>
```

or

```
<Location ~ "/*" >
  RequestHeader set X-test_url "Test"
</Location>
```

It's hard to explain how I've gotten to this point, but I have to get this done in Apache. Again I'm trying to add the header value to every request.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your first ought work alright.  I've just tested the following.  On a Red Hat system, I added `RequestHeader add X-LocalHeader "Headers For the Win"` to my httpd.conf file.

Then, I put together a quick Python script to dump my environment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
print 'Content-type: text/plain'
print

for tup in os.environ.items():
    print '%s: %s' % tup
```

Finally, an Apache restart and a `curl` yields the following:

```
[jeff@marvin ~]$ curl http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py
HTTP_ACCEPT: */*
HTTP_USER_AGENT: curl/7.19.7 
SERVER_NAME: localhost
REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.1
SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py
REMOTE_PORT: 42551
SERVER_SOFTWARE: Apache/2.2.13 (Fedora)
SERVER_ADMIN: root@localhost
SCRIPT_NAME: /cgi-bin/test.py
SERVER_SIGNATURE: Apache/2.2.13 

REQUEST_METHOD: GET
HTTP_HOST: localhost
SERVER_PORT: 80
GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
QUERY_STRING: 
PATH: /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
REQUEST_URI: /cgi-bin/test.py
HTTP_X_LOCALHEADER: Headers For the Win
SERVER_ADDR: 127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
```

As you can see, I have an 'HTTP_X_LOCALHEADER' value set, which corresponds to the header we added earlier.   It looks like you had it right, is it still not working?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too. For some reason it's not coming through.
Did you add it to your httpd.conf inside a virtual host or outside of one? The docs listed RequestHeaders as only valid inside of certain nodes, one of which was virtualhost.

Comment: Our config uses multiple files so I was trying to avoid editing the httpd.conf. That being said I found a Directory node in the httpd.conf that matches all directories and adding the RequestHeader worked. Thanks for the advice and nice to see a hockey fan.

Comment: The same solution works in apache2 by editing /etc/apache2/apache2.conf